# IBM Rackswitch G8000 SNMP Temperature OID

Tags: switch, snmp, ibm, oid

Google hasn't been my friend today.

Does anyone know the OID for temperature statistics on Rackswitch G8000's?

Answer (score 0):

The text name for the variables appear to be [hwTemperatureSensor1, hwTemperatureSensor2, and hwTemperatureSensor3](http://www.snmplink.org/cgi-bin/nd/m/Ent/N/Nortel%20Networks/Alteon%20WebSystems%20%28AWS%29/Blade%20Network%20Technologies,%20Inc/RackSwitch%20G8000%20%28BLADEOS%29/G8000/6.x%20-%20Stacking%20L2%20only,%20no%20spanning%20tree/*256.0.1/GbTOR-1-10G-SC.mib). However, the actual OID number remains elusive.

I would recommend using a MIB walker/browser to dump all the OIDs and then search for text like `tempt` or `temperature`.